# AngularJS DateRangePicker CSS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following library:
 https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker

These are the script tags I am Using:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/momentjs/moment.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-daterangepicker/js/angular-daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css"/>
```

I cant find the following file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css"/>
```

Following is my initialization code:

```
$scope.datePicker = {startDate: moment().subtract(6, 'days'), endDate: moment()};
$scope.dateRangeOptions = {
    applyClass: 'btn-green',
    locale: {
        applyLabel: "Apply",
        fromLabel: "From",
        format: "YYYY-MM-DD", //will give you 2017-01-06
        toLabel: "To",
        cancelLabel: 'Cancel'
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input date-range-picker  class="form-control date-picker" type="text" ng-model="datePicker"  options="dateRangeOptions"/>
```

The CSS is not working and the UI is all broken.

Comment: maybe you should bower install bootstrap-daterangepicker. can you locate your missing file in your project?

Comment: the css file for daterangepicker seems to be coming with the name daterangepicker.css. But on the github page, they have referenced  daterangepicker-bs3.css which I don't have

Comment: Are you using the same package version as you are seeing on github and you have downloaded?

Comment: @CharuMaheshwari thanks a lot. Working now after matching versions!!